# How to show 'staff' of certain 'shop' correctly?

Tags: python, html, django

[image]

[image]

As you can see in a picture I have Staff Worker named Max Barren but the thing is he is connected only to one of these shops. How do I write code properly for this staff worker only under one of these shops?

views.py

```
def list_view(request):

    context = {}

    context['library_dataset'] = VideoLibrary.objects.all()
    context['staff_dataset'] = Staff.objects.all()
    context['rank_dataset'] = Rank.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/list_view.html', context)
```

at views.py I get objects like address and shop name from the VideoLibrary model and staff_name and gender from the Staff model to put it in list_view.html

models.py

```
class VideoLibrary(models.Model):
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    adress = models.TextField(max_length=264, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shop_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Video Libraries"


class Staff(models.Model):
    staff_name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    living_adress = models.TextField(max_length=264)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    staff_rating = models.IntegerField()
    shop_name = models.ForeignKey(VideoLibrary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.staff_name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Staff"


class Rank(models.Model):
    # rank_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    staff_name = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank_name = models.CharField(max_length=264)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.rank_name}, {self.staff_name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Ranks"
```

I suppose I got some trouble with my code at list_view.html but I don't know how to figure it out

list_view.html

```
<div class="main">
      {% for data in library_dataset %} Shop name:
      <br />
      <br />
      {{ data.shop_name }} <br />
      {{ data.adress }} <br />

      <td><a href="{% url 'update_shop' data.id  %}">
        <button type="button">Edit Shop Details</button>
        </a></td>

      <br />
      Staff that work in the shop:
      {% for data in staff_dataset %} Shop name:
      <br />
      <br />
      {{ data.staff_name }} <br />
      {{ data.gender }} <br />

      <td><a href="{% url 'update_staff' data.id  %}">
        <button type="button">Edit User Details</button>
        </a></td>
      <br />
      <br />
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      <br>
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing to context all VideoLibrary objects and all Staff objects. So when you are doing

```
{% for data in library_dataset %} 
   Displaying data of all shops
  {% for data in staff_dataset %}
   Displaying data of all staff
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

You display every user in database for every shop in your database. You should use related name of staff from your VideoLibrary object. More on that here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects
In your case it would be probably .staff_set.all() to get all staff objects related to shop, so your html code would be:

```
{% for data in library_dataset %} 
   Displaying data of all shops
  {% for staff in data.staff_set.all %}
   Displaying data of staff related to libary
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: is there any way to relate to additional model? I have model rank and when i type {% for rank in data.rank_set.all %} nothing happens. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Does your rank has foreign key to VideoLibrary?

Comment: i added some code in my question - it is related to Staff not to VideoLibrary

Comment: Okay, you have ForeignKey to rank on Staff object, so you would need to add iteration over staff.rank_set.all, not videolibary

Comment: is there any way to write logic that will check if there is any staff worker in this library, if not - types that there is no any staff worker in the library?

Comment: You can check if data.staff_set.all and if yes - iterate over it, else display message about no staff in libary